NULL column value is filtered by != operator. Proper way to filter LEFT JOIN results?
I use sqlite to filter objects. Now I have problems with filtering results from LEFT JOIN.
UPD: ok, I understand why it is going on, but I would like to know what is proper way to filter results after LEFT JOIN.
Without filter I have likewise selected table:



Id
prop




1
"a"


1
"b"


2
"c"


3
NULL


4
NULL



I use following WHERE filter to get rows from this table that has prop not equal to "b".
I use following expression in WHERE: WHERE prop != 'b' and I expect following table as result:



Id
prop




1
"a"


2
"c"


3
NULL


4
NULL



But unexpectedly to me, the result doesn't include 3 and 4 ids:



Id
prop




1
"a"


2
"c"



Why is that happened and what should I do with it? Changing prop != 'b' to prop != 'b' OR prop IS NULL looks quite strange.
I don't understand, what motivation for sql bases to filter rows like that and therefore can't understand if there is something better than transforming filter expression as above.

Modern SQL has a single (if incredibly verbose) operator for this: x IS DISTINCT FROM y and x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM y.  SQLite supports it, fortunately.

Regarding your edit you can use prop IS NOT 'b' as synonymous with prop  IS DISTINCT FROM 'b' according to https://sqlite.org/forum/info/40e591aed9598c33ddc22e9cb1d9a11b030768319efa51c4f97b937f5f02ec84

The rule of thumb in SQL is that any comparison of a column against NULL using either = or != is unknown.  This is because NULL itself semantically represents an unknown value in SQL.
So the condition WHERE prop != 'b' for NULL values of prop evaluate to "unknown," which by default are treated as not true or rather false.
To be clear:
prop | expression  | result
NULL | prop = 'b'  | FALSE
NULL | prop != 'b' | FALSE
'b'  | prop = 'b'  | TRUE
'c'  | prop != 'b' | TRUE

